# When do we use “il” and “ce”? — Quand doit-on utiliser « il » ou « ce » ?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-personnels, démonstratifs

Is there a rule to when "il", "elle" are used and when "ce", "cela", etc. are used?

> **C**'est sympa. (*It is nice*)
>
> Y a-t-**il** une librairie près d'ici? (*Is there a bookstore nearby?*)

---

Y a-t-il une règle qui indique quand utiliser « il » et « elle » et quand utiliser « ce » et « cela » ?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections Stéphane. Evidently I forgot a LOT of French grammar.

Comment: The examples you give are two very *very* special cases. *Ce* as a subject is almost only used with the verb *être* (or *pouvoir être*, *devoir être*, maybe a few others), and *y avoir* is an impersonal verbal locution (the *il* in “il y a” is as meaningless as the *it* in “it rains”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An advice which seems to give some insight for this would be: if you can substitute the *it* in the English sentence by a *this* or *that* then it is probably a *ce*, *cela* and other variants of them which is needed in French. You have to be aware that the *it* pronoun (neutral gender) does not exist in French, that is why it might be tedious to translate sentences such as "This mountain is so big. It should be at least 3,000 meters high.", for which you have to know the gender of the word *montagne* in French.

More generally, *ce*, *cela* (*cet*, *cette*, *ceux*, etc.) are demonstrative pronoun which means they refer to something you already mentioned or something which is obvious according to the context. Whereas *il* and *elle* are just the French equivalent of *he* and *she*, plus the expression *there is/are* in English which translation is *il y a* in French.

Comment: Ton exemple ne colle pas à l'explication : on ne dirait ni « *this is a good friend » ni « *il est un bon compagnon ».

Comment: En écrivant je me suis rendu compte que cet exemple ne fonctionnait pas mais, tout de même, il me semble que l'astuce permet de résoudre beaucoup de cas. Après, il existe toujours des exceptions et si vous avez une règle plus générale je suis preneur!