# When to use "parce qu'il/elle" and "parce que c'est"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, conjonctions

When you are justifying opinions using the word 'because' could someone explain when you would use these two forms? :

- *Parce qu'il* / *Parce qu'elle*

  > J'aime bien la musique parce qu'elle est amusante.
- *Parce que c'est*

  > J'aime aller à la piscine parce que c'est près d'ici.

Comment: You might equally say "J'aime aller à la piscine parce qu'elle est près d'ici" or even the less idomatic "J'aime bien la musique parce que c'est amusant".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si ces formules sont équivalentes dans leur globalité, on notera cependant une nuance :
*If those formulas seem to be equivalent, there are in face slightly different in meaning:*

> J'aime aller à la/cette piscine parce qu'elle n'est pas loin d'ici.
>
> J'aime cette musique parce qu'elle est entraînante.

On utilise cette forme-ci pour parler non pas de quelque chose en général mais d'une instance : une piscine en particulier, une musique en particulier...
*With this formulation, we don't speak about something in general but about an instance: one particular swimming pool, one particular music style or song.*

Ceci est légèrement différent :
*This is slightly different:*

> J'aime aller à la piscine parce que c'est...
>
> J'aime la musique parce que c'est...

On utilisera plutôt cette forme-là pour parler de façon plus générale : les piscines en général, la musique au sens large du terme.
*We use this formulation to speak in a more general way: swimming pools in general, music in general.*

Comment: merci, exactement ce que je cherchais!

Comment: Pour que les premiers exemples soient tout à fait clairs, peut-être remplacer par « J'aime aller à **cette** piscine/J'aime **cette** musique ». En dépit de tes explications, on peut être déconcerté par le début de phrase qui utilise un « la » général et la proposition subordonnée qui s'applique à un cas particulier.

Comment: Cette tournure avec le « la » général (bien que pas tout à fait claire) est encore la plus courante (du moins pour le cas du lieu : le lieu en question se définit de lui-même dans l'esprit des locuteurs, en fonction de leurs habitudes, de leur situation géographique...).
Cependant, on entend plutôt "cette musique", en effet.

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences use *parce que*. You have to compare “parce qu'elle” in the first sentence to “parce que ce” in the second. The last *e* of *parce que* is [elided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision_%28French%29) only in the first because *elle* starts with a vowel but not *ce*.

Therefore, the only difference lies in the choice of the subject pronoun in the second clause of this sentence.
Whether to use *il/elle* or *ce* has [already been discussed](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7621/when-do-we-use-il-and-ce-quand-doit-on-utiliser-il-ou-ce) on French Language. It is not linked to the use of *parce que* and it's particularly subtle in these examples. In the two examples you gave both *elle* and *ce* would do, but it is not always the case.

Comment: +1 parce tu soulignes l'équivalence des deux formulations : "J'aime [...] parce {que c'est|qu'elle est} [...]".

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is the same as *"because"*.

You are removing an *"**e**"* before a word starting with a vowel to *"parce que"* for the same reason you are adding a *"n"* to the indefinite article *"a"* in english : **language fluency**.

---

Here some examples :

---

- Parce qu'il ment = Because he is lying
- Parce que tu mens = Because you are lying

Those two sentences mean the same but have different subjects.

*"Parce qu'"* will be used with *"il"*, *"elle"*, *"on"*, *"ils"* et *"elles"* while "*Parce que*" will be used with  *"je"*, *"tu"*, *"nous"* et *"vous"*.

---

- Parce qu'un chat mange les souris = Because a cat eats mice
- Parce que le chat mange les souris = Because the cat eats mice

Here, there is no difference in meaning, just pointing at a cat in particular (second case) or characterising all of them (first case).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple reason actually. Both sentences use the same form, "parce que". But in french, when the next word starts with a vowel, the last 'e' of "parce que" is changed for an apostrophe.

`Parce qu'il mange` means in fact `parce que il mange`, but we use a contracted form.